# Extract chosen element of the vector in the list

Tags: r, string, list, character

Let's consider list following:

```
listed_list <- list(
  list("something", 2), list("cool", 3),
  list(c("big", "small"), c(2, 3)),
  list(c("huge", "not", "small"), c(3, 4, 5))
)
```

As you can see first element of the list is a string or vector of strings. What I want to have is to extract specific element, regardless it's in a vector or not.

In this example I would like to have for extracting first element:

`"something", "cool", "big", "huge"`

If second then

`"small", "not"`

If third then

`"small"`

because I'm always extracting the very first element.

And I'm not sure how to do it in the simpler way. I tried with sapply:

```
unlist(sapply(listed_list, "[[", 1))
```

but pure use of sapply is not solving the issue (which is logical - it output first element of the first regardless it's simple string or vector).

Could you please give me a hand how it can be done ?

Comment: `purrr::map`  as using : `map(map(listed_list, 1),1)` for first , `map(map(listed_list, 1),2)` for second etc

Answer (score 0):

```
foo <- function(L, i) {
  res <- lapply(L, "[[", 1)
  res <- res[lengths(res) >= i]
  vapply(res, "[[", i, FUN.VALUE = character(1))
}

foo(listed_list, 1)
#[1] "something" "cool"      "big"       "huge"   
foo(listed_list, 2)
#[1] "small" "not" 
foo(listed_list, 3)
#[1] "small"
```

Comment: Thanks! That's quite clever, highlighting fact that you used only base R functions. I presume that in the first line of the function `listed_list` should be replaced by `L`. But in your case it doesn't matter